# How does one control if allocated memory is stored in L1,L2, L3 cache or other in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, memory-management

Speeds of L1 cache are faster than L2 and so on and so forth. How does one control where the memory is allocated to In JavaScript? How does one see where the memory is being allocated to?

I understand is most likely not possible. I'm asking the question in this manner to avoid a boolean question.

Comment: JavaScript does not provide a way to control this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One does not control memory allocation in JavaScript.

Also, caches are supposed to be transparent, they are automatically managed by the hardware. You just allocate RAM, not specific cache memory, and when you use it it will get cached. You'd have a very hard time to manually control this, even in lower-level languages.